# spring batch compositeItemWriter chunk customization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am writing spring batch job for below scenerio.

1. CustomItemReader will read the data from rest url
2. CustomItemProcess will process those records.
3. I need to write the processed data in 2 tables , one table just write all the data based on chunk interval and another table write the  commulative sum data .ie aggregate data

I had written compositeItemWriter but that will insert the records based on chunk in all the writer , is there way can we apply chunk only on first writer not on the second writer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all composing writers of the composite will receive the same items of the current chunk.